# Complex number division error in python

Tags: python, division, complex-numbers

Something ridiculous happened while handling complex numbers.

```
> complex(1,2)/complex(1,2)  
(1+0j)
```

This one was nice, but...

```
>complex(15,22)/complex(15,22)   
(1-5.51196762578357e-17j)
```

*(WHAT?)*

```
> a=complex(15,22)/complex(15,22)  
> a.imag  
-5.51196762578357e-17  
> int(a.imag)==a.imag  
False
```

Surely the imaginary part is not zero...
Please try it on your own and witness this ironic situation.

One more example.

```
> print c  
(74+33j)   
> c/(1+10j)   
(4-7.000000000000001j)
```

Of course, that `-7.0000000000000000001` should have been `-7`.

Comment: Just a rounding error... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (it's actually kind of expected that it works with 1 and 2 because they are both powers of 2, while 15 and 22 aren't.)

Comment: Plz tell me much much easier.. I'm not a skilled programmer(and not able to read the whole document you posted cause I'm not good at reading English) I need more childlike advices...

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), there are tons of answers between child-like and deep technical. In short: Computers only have so-much precision when calculating, so there will always be rounding errors. The rounding errors will look weird in decimal notation because computers do the math in binary. For example, if a human rounds 1/3 then it will be something like 0.333..., and (1/3)*3 with this 3-digit precision would give 0.999 instead of 1. The same thing happens here, but just with different number bases.